# Use javascript variable elsewhere in page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a page that has a number of sliders that allow users to select a value between two ranges.  Whenever the slider moves the numbers are updated etc and a new figure is displayed.

To expand this I would like to add a free text field where users can enter numbers that are then subtracted from the total.

I have the following code but do not know how to pass the variable to the existing javascript, if i just use expenseamount then nothing is displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#expense").change(function(){
var expenseamount = $(this).val(); 
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help so far but still nothing happening - my full script is now below:

```
<script> 
$( ".slider" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 50,
min:10,
max: 100,
step: 10,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#slider-result" ).html( ui.value );
},
});

var amount= $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" );

var expenseamount;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#expense").change(function(){
expenseamount = $(this).val(); 
});
});

amount2 = amount - expenseamount;
$("#total" ).text(amount2);

</script>
```

Comment: if you don't use `var`, it's going to be global.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker thats bad advice. Always use `var` just use it where you mean to use it.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Not the solution, you should always use `var`. Just put `var expenseamount;` outside the `$(document)...` function and use it then without `var`: `expenseamout = ...`.

Comment: @AlexWayne, it's hard to give a better advice without knowing a thing about the code. Generally, yes, I agree, polluting the global scope is  a capital offence.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that you declare `expenseamount` as a global variable before you use it.  It will then be available to all scripts in your project.  Declaring it inside the `.ready()` handler makes it a local variable inside that handler function so it's not available elsewhere in your project.  Here's how you would declare it as a global variable:

```
script type="text/javascript">

var expenseamount;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expense").change(function(){
        expenseamount = $(this).val(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

It is generally a good practice to add the fewest global variables possible because they can conflict with each other.  If you're only going to have one global like this or it's a pretty simple app, then the above technique is fine.

If, on the other hand, your app was pretty big and perhaps was part of a larger project that other people were contributing code to, then you probably want to take measures to avoid global variable conflicts.  In that case, you would create a single top level global variable and add items like this as properties on it:

```
script type="text/javascript">

// make sure myAppGlobals is defined as an object
// but if it has already been defined, don't overwrite it
var myAppGlobals = myAppGlobals || {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expense").change(function(){
        myAppGlobals.expenseamount = $(this).val(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Haha, who says that there are hundreds of correct answers to every JavaScript question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take out the `var` and it would make `expenseamount` a global variable. But that would be dreadful when it comes to proper coding practices.

I suggest you create some sort of object to hold common data like this and make it global. Probably want to add some simple namespacing, too:

```
var AppData = AppData || {};

AppData.expenseAmount = 0;

//...

$(doument).ready(function () {
    $("#expense").change(function(){
        AppData.expenseAmount = $(this).val(); 
    });
});

//...

function someOtherFunction() {
    alert(AppData.expenseAmount); //you get the point.
}
```

**PS** - This is a "should work anywhere" kind of fix. You should consider your specific situation and the abilities of JavaScript to do awesome stuff (like closures) to limit the availability of `expenseAmount` to only where it's needed. So, to clarify, this isn't the *best* solution, it's the *best solution I can offer without knowing more about your code structure*. You should endeavor to improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope, which means that variables defined in functions are inly availble in those functions. So instead, declare you variable in the scope you intend it to exist in, the global scope.

```
var expenseamount;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#expense").change(function(){
    expenseamount = $(this).val(); 
  });
});

// expenseamount can now be used from anywhere
```